# How to clear Asp.Net MVC's session variable when leaving the web page?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, session

This is my method.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["visited"] ==null|| (int)Session["visited"] != 1)
        {
            Session["visited"] = 0;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I used it in the view to check the session variable to load a style sheet for animation. This the code which I have in the _Layout page to inject css style sheet in to the layout.

```
@if(Session["visited"]!=null&&(int)Session["visited"]==0)
    {
        @Html.CreateStyleSheet();
        Session["visited"] = 1;
    }
```

Hey folks I just wanted to say before you solve this I want to know how to clear session data when exiting the page. Nothing else. So do not over think it.

Comment: Why do you want to clear the session when leaving the page?  The whole *point* of session state is to exist across page requests.  I guess you could clear the session in some code block at the end of your view, since that would likely be the last thing executed in your code, but it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually looking for a model or a querystring parameter.

Comment: Sessions are stored on the servers.  Leaving the page happens on the client, and the server is never notified.  The hard part is going to be notifying the server that the client has left the page.  As far as I know, there is no clean and easy way to do this.

Comment: The only way would be to bind to something like `onunload` and send an AJAX request to an MVC action (Web API action won't work because it has no access to the session). You'd also need to make the AJAX request synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how to clear session data when exiting the page

There isn't really an "exiting the page" event.  You'd either clear the values as the last thing you do when rendering the page, or the first thing you do when another page is requested.  And the line of code to do it is:

```
Session.Clear()
```

So if this should be done at the end of rendering the page, then simply add that to the end of your view.  (If it should be done at the end of *every* page then add it to the end of the layout view.)  The idea here is that the view is likely to be the last code executed server-side (aside from framework-internal code that doesn't use your values), so the last line in the view is the last thing you control.

---

Note, however, that this makes *very little sense*.  If you don't want your session data to persist from one page to the next then you shouldn't be using session state in the first place.  You're not actually tracking anything in the session if you clear that value every time.

Comment: If you just want to remove a single item, such as "visited", then you should use `Session.Remove("visited")`, instead.